# Issue extracting macOS created TAR archive with BusyBox

Tags: linux, macos, tar

I have created a tar on my Mac with the following command:

```
$ tar -czvf test.tar.gz test/
```

Extracting it on my target system (BusyBox) gives me the following error message:

```
$ tar xzvf test.tar.gz
tar: corrupted octal value in tar header
```

I googled and found some other folks who had the same problem.

Apparently it's an incompatibility between the two implementations.

I tried `$ brew install gnu-tar` and then `$ gtar -czvf test.tar.gz test/` but it is still not working.

Unfortunately I did not find another solution.

```
$ tar
BusyBox v1.13.2 (2012-04-08 17:28:57 CDT) multi-call binary

$ tar --version
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3

$gtar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.29
```

**UPDATE**:

```
gtar -czvf test.tar.gz test/ --format=posix
```

Works but it still generates skipping header warnings:

```
tar: warning: skipping header 'x'
```

Comment: Why don't you use busybox also on osx? https://github.com/daliworks/busybox-osx

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks for the suggestion, any idea how I can get it installed? I did `brew install gnu-sed` but now I'm stuck, the INSTALL file is not really helping either.